# Convert friends to subscribers in Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to convert your Facebook friends to subscribers? I have read that some people did it, but I can't find any info about it.

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24198/convert-friends-to-subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

By Default, your Friends are your Subscribers.

But, still if you want him/her on Subscriber List, just Unfriend the person and they will become your subscriber

Comment: please use backticks only for code, not for "highlighting"

Comment: Much as I would love this to be correct it is not!